# Как скопировать полученные параметры в буфер обмена в iOS Safari c помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Получаю параметры из URL таким способом:

```
    <span id="pwd_spn" class="password-span" style="visibility: hidden"><?php echo  htmlspecialchars($_GET["clickid"]) . ':' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["device"]) . ':' . 
    htmlspecialchars($_GET["country"]);?></span>
```

Затем эти параметры нужно скопировать в буфер обмена. Но код, который я использую не работает в iOS >=11.
Нашёл код, который должен решить эту проблему:

```
  function iosCopyToClipboard(el) {
var oldContentEditable = el.contentEditable,
    oldReadOnly = el.readOnly,
    range = document.createRange();

el.contentEditable = true;
el.readOnly = false;
range.selectNodeContents(el);

var s = window.getSelection();
s.removeAllRanges();
s.addRange(range);

el.setSelectionRange(0, 999999);

el.contentEditable = oldContentEditable;
el.readOnly = oldReadOnly;

document.execCommand('copy');
```

}

Как мне сделать чтобы этот код копировал полученные параметры при нажатии на кнопку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не получится скопировать в буффер данные, которые содержит ваш , так как стиль у него "visibility: hidden", скройте текст каким-то другим способом, ниже работающий пример.

```js
const cobyToBuffer = () => {
  const textToBuffer =  document.getElementById("pwd_spn"),
  range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNode(textToBuffer);
      window.getSelection().addRange(range);
      try {
        document.execCommand('copy');
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();

}

const btn = document.getElementById("startCopy");
btn.addEventListener("click", cobyToBuffer, false);
```

```css
#pwd_spn{
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
 <span id="pwd_spn" class="password-span">example:return:from:php:query:params</span>
<button id="startCopy">Copy to buffer</button>
```